# Using .replaceWith() on dialog box. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to toggle the JQuery [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) using a button.

To replace the text in the dialog I use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

The problem is, that the text isn't replaced, and the dialog shows up, even when I have set

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Can you confirm?" style="display: none;">
```

Here is the code

```
(function() {
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});

function showhide(iname) {
    var item = document.getElementById(iname).style;
    if (item.display == 'none') {
    item.display = '';
    } else {
    item.display = 'none';
    }
}

$('div.dialog-text').replaceWith( "<b>New text goes here</b>" );
```

and can be tried out live at

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/XxVtU/

Also, if there is a better way, please let me know =)

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain your problem in more detail please ?

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: are you looking for a way to open that dialog with clicking the link above? And while doing this you also want to replace text that is mentioned on the dialog div, right?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for pointing that out. Now updated.

Comment: @lazycoder: Yes exactly. The showhide function was the only way I could think of. But being able to initialize the dialog plugin when needed, is really what I want =)

Comment: I guess the fiddle needs to be revised a bit as well. It loads mootools and jQuery, has two HTML, HEAD and BODY tags etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (for some reason) want to use replace the text using .replaceWith() method, you should make use of the callbacks (in this case the "create" or "open" callback") that are available in jQueryUI.

I've added an updated version of your own code doing what I thought you were trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/XxVtU/7/

Answer (score 2):

The text replacement seems to be working in Chrome 11, Firefox 4 and IE 9.  The dialog appears because you're initializing the dialog plugin in the document ready event handler and jQuery UI sets new styles (including `display`) to the dialog.  If you want it to be hidden, either hide it afterwards or initialize it only when you need it.

With it being a modal dialog, the clicking the link to hide it will never work because of the overlay, so you're probably wanting to only ever initialize the dialog box when you need to show it.  To that effect, I moved your initialization code from the ready handler to the `showhide` function:

```
function showhide(iname) {
    $("#" + iname).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XxVtU/8/

---

As T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comments, there's also `autoOpen: false`, which can be applied during initialization.  I modified your fiddle to [demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/XxVtU/11/).

Comment: You are right. The text is replaced. I don't know why I didn't notice that. How do I initialize dialog plugin on demand? That is what I really want. The showhide function was an ugly hack to get that functionality.

Comment: @Sandra: look at the example I provided and the source code I posted, it appears to do exactly what you want - initializing the dialog when the show/hide link is clicked.

Comment: +1 Another option is to use the `autoOpen: false` option and then open the dialog later using the 'open' command. If for any reason you want to initialize it before showing it.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing in you code is saying,

`when the page finishs loading display a dialog box`

give your `<a>` tag an id, and
you need to add a handler in your initialzation code.
Also, you were using anonymous functions, `function () { }`,in your document ready call; which is fine, but it can get kind of cluttery after a while..

For Example:

```
 function init() 
    {
        $("#my_a_tag_id").click(showDialog);
    }

function showDialog() {
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

Answer (score 1):

[take a look at this;](http://jsfiddle.net/msusur/XxVtU/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#showhide").click(function() {
 $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                    "Okay": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });});$('div.dialog-text').replaceWith( "<b>New text goes here</b>" );});
```